# How to get current server UTC time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

```
   var k=new Date();
   alert(k);
```

It alert local time. But I need to display current server UTC time.

Comment: Your server should expose an end point for that

Comment: Maybe take a look at moment.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is basically on client side. You will not be able to get server time  in java script as it will be executed on client and give you the server time only (Node.js is exception here).

If you really wish to have server time in javascript. You can write a **Api** or **Webservice** on serverside which will give you **server time** in format you want. Call this webservice/Api using **XMLHTTP** or **Ajax** request and parse the response and display the time as per your wish.

Ajax post Code Example :

```
        $.post( "Your Web Service Page", function( data ) {
          //Assuming that Your web service will not need any paramerter 
           and just write the server time in utc in response
          alert(data ); 

        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this `new Date().toUTCString()`

Comment: Various answers are submitted to this. please accept one answer so that status of this question changed to answered.